# Delphi Convert Set Of Bits as TBits to Integer or unsigned int

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Ihave value from nor or xor gate with represented as TBits and i want to convert it to generic variable like integer or unsigned integer my current working ide Tokyo 10.2

```
var
  ABits: TBits;
  AComulative: UInt32;

const
  PosBitFromSensor1 = 0;
  PosBitFromSensor2 = 1;

begin
  ABits := TBits.Create;
  try
    ABits.Size := 32;
    {GetValFromSensor return Boolean type}
    ABits.Bits[PostBitFromSensor1] := GetValFromSensor(PosBitFromSensor1); 
    ABits.Bits[PostBitFromSensor2] := GetValFromSensor(PosBitFromSensor2);
    AComulative := SomeBitsConvertToInteger(ABits); {some function like this}
  finally
    ABits.Free;
  end;
end;
```

or any simple solution.

Comment: With a class helper you might do [something like](https://pastebin.com/vEpwVFLB).

Comment: See [Can i access TBits internal bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11375619/576719)

Comment: wait i check it first.

Comment: @LURD, that won't work in Tokyo. But you can write `with Self do` for this crack.

Comment: @Victoria, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @LURD, noticed :)

Comment: victoria, LU RD, thanks i chose solution from victoria more friendly with generic Type Casting AComulative := UInt32(ABitset.ToUInt32);

Comment: There's no need for typecast. You'd just write `AComulative := ABits.ToUInt32;` as the result is already `UInt32` ;-)

Comment: you right vic. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be very fast but you can do regular bit manipulation, set each bit that corresponds to a "true" in the boolean array . For example:

```
function SomeBitsConvertToInteger(ABits: TBits): UInt32;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if ABits.Size <> SizeOf(Result) * 8 then
    raise EBitsError.Create('Invalid bits size');
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to Pred(SizeOf(Result) * 8) do
    Result := Result or UInt32((Ord(ABits[i]) shl i));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this :

```
type

  {$IF CompilerVersion > 32} // tokyo
    {$MESSAGE Fatal 'Check if TBits still has the exact same fields and adjust the IFDEF'}
  {$ENDIF}
  TPrivateAccessBits = class
  public
    FSize: Integer;
    FBits: Pointer;
  end;

Move(@TPrivateAccessBits(ABits).FBits, AComulative, sizeOf(AComulative));
```

Comment: This is very unsafe and may break in any future version of the run-time library.

Comment: The class helper, being already failed once, is probably likelier to fail in the future.

Comment: @Sertac: But the ''mode'' of failure would likely be much nicer (won't compile vs "very strange behaviour somewhere in the code")!

Comment: After the hurricane that emb face after they decide to remove private access from class helper I really doubt emb will decide one day to remove this feature ;) If they do it, I can say you that many of the muti tiers controls will not work anymore !

Comment: @Andreas - That's fair. An ifdef that would fail in newer version until the layout is checked would be nice.

Comment: I add the $MESSAGE WARN to make this code very safe !

Comment: this is a question of taste :) me i prefer the warning but nothing forbid to replace it by an error ...

Comment: ooh you mean i forget to @  ... i didn't test i wrote fastly the code

Comment: No, staying safe or not is a matter of personal taste. Definition of safety is not. You cannot bypass an error, you can bypass a warning.

Comment: @sertac : maybe you notice that on road their is green light and red light (and orange light to warn you to speed up), but their is no gate ;) and when you drive, you are not facing bug, just your life ;) ... and i assure you that if we replace all light by gate, they will be huge amount of complain !! so Maybe it's not matter of personal taste, but mater of point of view ;)

Comment: @loki: if your answer is sloppily coded, the user, especially a beginner, may not be able to understand and use your answer. If you did not test the code, say so, or use a phrase like "do something like".

Comment: @loki: the fact remains: it is only safe if it is an error. It ispersonal taste whether you ignore a warning or not. It is not personal taste to ignore an error: you can't.

Comment: Why not do `{$MESSAGE Fatal 'Check if TBits still has the exact same fields and adjust the IFDEF'}`?

Answer (score 1):

this solution provided by @Victoria and @LURD it maybe usefull for the other that have same solving problem. sorry about my English.

```
type
  TBitsHelper = class helper for TBits
  public
    function ToUInt32: UInt32;
  end;

{ TBitsHelper }

function TBitsHelper.ToUInt32: UInt32;
type
  PUInt32 = ^UInt32;
begin
  if Size > SizeOf(Result) * 8 then
    raise EOverflow.Create('Size overflow!');
  with Self do
    Result := PUInt32(FBits)^;
end;
```