# How can I create a TBitSet32 record in Delphi for efficient 32-bit operations?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I am working on a project where I need to manipulate a set of 32 bits very efficiently. Memory efficiency is crucial, so using an array of boolean (which would occupy 32 bytes) is not an option (if I can have other choice, speed is the most important).

Here's the structure I am envisioning for my TBitSet32:

```
TBitSet32 = record 
    value: ?integer?; // I'm not sure about the datatype here. Should it be Integer or another type?

    // Gets the value associated with a particular bit index.
    function valueForBit(index: integer): boolean;

    // Returns the number of marked bits in the set.
    function count: integer;

    // Marks the specified bit.
    procedure markBit(value: boolean; index: integer);   
end;
```

For the value field, I presume I need a 32-bit integer type. Is Integer the correct choice here? How can I implement the valueForBit, count, and markBit methods?

I would appreciate any insights or sample implementations for this record.

Comment: Have you checked https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TBits already? Is it to much unefficent for your case?

Comment: What about TIntegerSet?

Comment: @DelphiCoder The main problem with `TBits` is that there is no easy way to a assign those bits then to some numerical value like Integer variable for instance. This greatly limits the usability of `TBits` class. If `TBits` would at least provide ability for programmer to manually change the internal FBits pointer that points to the memory location that `TBits` operate on.

Comment: @SilverWarior this could probably help with the problem you mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438669/delphi-convert-set-of-bits-as-tbits-to-integer-or-unsigned-int

Comment: Note that casting bits to integers is endian dependent anyway.

Comment: Isn't this just `set of 0..31` plus the usual set operations?

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)

Comment: What does the System.Classes.TBits class not have that you would need?

Comment: @DelphiCoder Yes the question you linked provides two viable solutions. First answer that is marked recommends looping trough `TBits` elements and using bit-wise operations on final result  which raises a question of why not use bit-wise operations before and skipping the use of `TBits` entirely. Second answer by Dicky Tamara recommends using class helper which is much more elegant solution but it assumes that you would always be assigning value of `TBits` to unsigned 32 bit integer. I'm guessing this is because what OP of that question wanted. ...

Comment: ... Any way if I ever ended up using `TBits` it would probably for deriving my own class from it which would allow me to use the said class on an existing variable. This could be done by passing the said variable as var argument to the class constructor. This way inside constructor I could set `FBits` field to point to the variable location and set `FSize` field to be matching the size of the passed variable. So a few lines more and I would have more usable solution. But before that I would have to test to see if `TBits` is properly taking into account Little-endianor Big-endian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need exactly 32 bits, then `(U)Int32` would make more sense than `Integer`.  The rest is just a matter of bit manipulation using the `and`, `or`, and `shl`/`shr` operators, eg:

```
type
  TBitSet32 = record 
    FSet: UInt32;

    // Gets the value associated with a particular bit index.
    function valueForBit(index: integer): boolean;

    // Returns the number of marked bits in the set.
    function count: integer;

    // Marks the specified bit.
    procedure markBit(value: boolean; index: integer);   
  end;

function TBitSet32.valueForBit(index: integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := (FSet and (1 shl index)) <> 0;
end;

function TBitSet32.count: integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  tmp: UInt32;
begin
  Result := 0;
  tmp := FSet;
  for I := 0 to 31 do begin
    Inc(Result, tmp and 1);
    tmp := tmp shr 1;
  end;
end;

procedure markBit(value: boolean; index: integer);
begin
  if value then
    FSet := FSet or (1 shl index)
  else
    FSet := FSet and not (1 shl index);
end;
```

That said, consider using a `Set` instead, and let the compiler handle the bit manipulation for you, as a `Set` is implemented using a bit set, eg:

```
type
  TBitSet32 = record 
    FSet: set of 0..31;

    // Gets the value associated with a particular bit index.
    function valueForBit(index: integer): boolean;

    // Returns the number of marked bits in the set.
    function count: integer;

    // Marks the specified bit.
    procedure markBit(value: boolean; index: integer);   
  end;

function TBitSet32.valueForBit(index: integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := index in FSet;
end;

function TBitSet32.count: integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 0 to 31 do
    Inc(Result, Ord(I in FSet));
end;

procedure markBit(value: boolean; index: integer);
begin
  if value then
    Include(FSet, index)
  else
    Exclude(FSet, index);
end;
```

Comment: thanks, the FSet: set of 0..31; seam the most promising solution !

Comment: @zeus, you may also make `valueForBit` and `markBit` functions private and implement public `property Bits[index: integer]: Boolean read valueForBit write markBit`. Then use `myBitSet.Bits[2] := true`